# Selecting 180 days from 366: the probability of even distribution across months, or not having September among the first 30

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In a draft lottery containing the 366 days of the year (including February 29). Select 180 days (draw 180 without replacement).
>
> a) What is the probability that the 180 days drawn are evenly distributed among the twelve months?
> b) What is the probability that the first 30 days drawn contain none from September?

I understood part a). But they say the answer for part b is:

Number of combinations of 336 taken 30 at a time / Number of combinations of 366 taken 30 at a time.

I understand the bottom but not the top.

When you take the number of combinations of 336 taken 30 at a time how can you make sure
you are letting out the 30 days from September and not other 30 days from any other month.
What would the top be if the question said: What is the probability that the first 30 days drawn contain none from December? The same top?

I do not think so. It is less likely for December than for September because Dec has 31 days.

I would appreciate your comments regarding my concern. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

(a)
$$ \displaystyle \frac{{31 \choose 15}{29 \choose 15}...{31 \choose 15}}{366 \choose 180}  $$

(b)
$$ {30 \choose 0}{336 \choose 180}\over  {366 \choose 180}   $$

Hypergeometric distribution. We divide the year up into different categories: 12 months in  (a)  and September versus the rest of the year in (b).
In both problems note how the sum across the "rows" is the same in the numerator and denominator:

31+29+...+31=366

15+15+...15=180.

30+336=366

0+180=180

This helps you make sure you've accounted for everything.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be much easier to read if it were in math display style rather than the in-line style. (If you insert \displaystyle in the math formatting, it leaves it in-line but expands the symbols to the same size as in a displayed equation.)

Answer (score 0):

The *September* part, besides informing us that we are talking about a group of 30 days, is **irrelevant**. We are not "sure" that we are taking out the 30 days from September, but the calulcation remains the same no matter which group of 30 days we are talking about.

Remember, we are not *sure* that anything happens, we are only calculating the *probability* that certain things happen. Just as the probability of throwing a die and getting a one is $\frac{1}{6}$, the probability of getting a six is also $\frac{1}{6}$. It doesn't matter whether we're talking about ones or sixes, the important thing is the possible number of outcomes, and the outcomes that we are interested in.

For December, it would have to be altered to account for the fact that December has 31 days, not 30, as you say, and then similar calculations take place.

Comment: Or the numerator could be changed to account for the fact that December has 31 days. It would just be 335 choose 30.

Comment: The opening sentence of this answer is just wrong, and the closing sentence makes this clear. What is true though is that the only relevance of "September" is that it has $30$ days, so replacing it by April, June, or November would make no difference.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I see what you're saying, but the OP was confused as to how we knew the 30 days were coming from september, and I wanted to clarify that it's the same regardless of which group of 30 days, as I am saying in the first paragraph. "September" certainly carries the information that we are talking about 30 days, not 31 or 28, but I don't think it caused confusion. I can edit a bit to make it clear.